# CSS position icon at top right of div, goes behind div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got a quick question. I want an icon at the top right of the div, and the bottom right. I think I am doing it well, but for some reason it goes behind the div.
[Image of what happens, you can see the green and red icon not going above it, but behind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDooj.png)

This is the code I wrote:

**HTML:**

```
<div v-if="showMenu" class="wrapper">

        <!-- Begin karakters onderaan -->
        <div v-if="karakters" class="karakters-wrapper">
            <span v-for="karakter in karakters" :key="karakter">

                <div v-if="karakter !== undefined" class="karakter-box">
                    <p>{{karakter.charinfo.firstname}} {{karakter.charinfo.lastname}}</p>
                    
                    <i class="fas fa-play-circle icoon-speel"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-trash icoon-verwijder"></i>
                </div>
                <div v-else class="karakter-box">
                    <p>Leeg karakter slot</p>
                </div>

            </span>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <h1 style="color:#fff;font-size:48px;">GEDULD!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Einde karakters onderaan -->
    </div>
```

^^ Don't mind the v-if etc. that's from VueJS. Anyways, the div with class "karakter-box" is the div where I want an icon at the top right of.

**CSS:**

````
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.karakters-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* Karakter boxjes */
.karakter-box {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    border-top: 8px solid var(--white);
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: var(--white);
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

.karakter-box:hover {
    border-top: 8px solid var(--groen);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}


.icoon-speel {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;

    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: var(--groen);
    color: var(--white);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.icoon-verwijder {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -10px;

    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: var(--rood);
    color: var(--white);
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}```
````

Comment: do you want your icons to be clickable ??

Comment: @AnonymousCoder Yes I do, but that's not the problem at this point of time. I think that would work fine if there is a css solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why but it looks like there is an `overflow: hidden` `karakter-box` class.
even though i don't see it in the code sample you provided.
When i tested the code the sample this issue did not occur
Try Checking for css `overflow` on `karakter-box`

Comment: There is no overflow on the CSS class sadly, nowhere in the css file

Comment: You were right! I am using reset.css file that resets all default CSS values, it had an overflow hidden in there! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use another  for the background and set its width to device width.
use this css code to get positions to right corners
Position: absolute;

and use this at css to get front of div
z-index:1;

index 1 is go front of styles and 2 3 4 going backward as ordered.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work, it's not really a problem with z-indexes but something else.

Answer (score 0):

set the z-index of div to be -1

```
div{
z-index: -1;
}
```

and that of icons to be 1

```
i{
z-index: 1;
}
```

i will make the div behind your icons, so you can interact with your icons.

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix it either :/

Comment: try to make value of z-index to be more bigger like 110